# Creating %'s from values that can be both positive and negative

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a report that is supposed to show inventory accuracy followed by accuracy percentage. The issue is that there can either an overage in the inventory(positive) or a shortage (negative). The percentage will be by location

ex.

```
Loc.         expected qty   Actual QTY    % 
Location 1   48              48          100%
Location 2   52              53          98%
Location 3   48              45          93%
Location 4   48              48          100%
```

How do I calculate the variance instead of just the ratio of expected to actual?

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily with a `CASE` statement. The tricky part is making sure you do your calculation on DECIMAL values. You can either start with DECIMALs and cast back to INT, or start with INTs and cast them to decimals in the calculation.

Here's an example using a temp table with your sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #table1
(
    loc INT
    ,[expected qty] DECIMAL(10, 1)
    ,[Actual QTY] DECIMAL(10, 1)
)

INSERT INTO #table1
(
    loc
    ,[expected qty]
    ,[Actual QTY]
)
VALUES
(1, 48, 48)
,(2, 52, 53)
,(3, 48, 45)
,(4, 48, 48)

SELECT
    loc
    ,[expected qty] = CAST([expected qty] AS INT)
    ,[Actual QTY] = CAST([Actual QTY] AS INT)
    ,[Acc %] = CAST(CASE WHEN [expected qty] >= [Actual QTY]
                         THEN ( [Actual QTY] / [expected qty] ) * 100
                    WHEN [expected qty] < [Actual QTY]
                        THEN 100 - ((( [Actual QTY] / [expected qty] ) * 100 ) - 100 ) END AS INT)
FROM #table1

DROP TABLE #table1
```

Results:

```
loc expected qty    Actual QTY  Acc % 
1   48              48          100 
2   52              53          98 
3   48              45          93 
4   48              48          100
```

Comment: SELECT Start_date_time AS "Start",  End_date_time AS "END", 
aisle AS "Aisle",
bay AS "Bay",
lvl AS "Level",
item AS "Item",
cast(expected_qty as INT) AS "Expected Qty",
Cast(actual_qty as INT) AS "Actual Qty",
cast(case when expected_qty >= actual_qty then (actual_qty/expected_qty)* 100 when expected_qty < actual_qty then 100 - (((actual_qty/expected_qty) * 100) -100) end as INT) AS "Variance",
user_name AS "User"
FROM CYCLE_CNT_HIST
WHERE whse = '1'
AND to_char(DATE_TIME,'MM-DD-YYYY') between '03-01-2019' and '03-22-2019'

Comment: So I tried it that Way of adding the cast and Case whens but when i would run it i would get "divisor is equal to zero" **sorry about the format ran out of characters to have the code in one comment